# как запустить файл с расширением js на хостинге

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hosting, ejs

Есть приложение для написания которого были использованы: библиотека express, шаблонизатор EJS. Впервые сталкиваюсь с nodejs, работой с хостингом. Перенесла локальный сайт на хостинг и не знаю как его запустить. У меня есть файл index.js, который должен запускать файл list.ejs. При переходе по url, который мне выдал хостинг для моего сайта я вижу папку с проектом, внутри которой лежат файлы, если я запускаю index.js вручную, то вижу просто код, который содержит этот файл, при открытии lest.ejs просто открывается верстка со стилями, но она не функционирует, что очевидно.
Подскажите, как мне запустить свой проект на сервере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит посмотреть на сайте хостинга (или уточнить в поддержке / базе знаний) имеется ли возможность запускать проекты на nodejs.

Если есть, то скорее всего у них есть также доступ по [SSH](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH) и запуск будет производиться из консоли (думаю так же, как Вы делаете это локально).